# MPMoviePlayerController buffering state

Tags: ios, media-player

Just a very short question:

How can I find out if the MPMoviePlayerController instance is buffering data (in this case audio data from a web stream)?

Thanks for any kind of help and have a nice day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register an object to be notified by the MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification and then access the `loadState` of the movie player.

See the notifications section of the [`MPMoviePlayerController` reference.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Is there a way to detect buffer size so it can be visually provided to the user?